# will a tcp program check missing packet before it passively closes a tcp connection after receiving a RST or FIN

Tags: tcp, network-programming

if there is a tcp connection between A and B, 
A send some packets and then a TCP RST(or TCP FIN/ACK) to close the connection,
let me say?

```
     PKT1, PKT2, PKT3, TCP_RST
```

or

```
     PKT1, PKT2, PKT3, TCP_FIN/ACK
```

but the packet arrival is out of order

```
    PKT1, TCP_RST(or TCP_FIN/ACK), PKT2, PKT3
```

then how will B react?

according to the sequence number of TCP_RST and TCP_FIN/ACK,
B knows there are some packets missing(PKT2 and PKT3), 
will B wait for PKT2 and PKT3 before it close the connection, 
or B immediately close the connection when it receives TCP_RST(or TCP_FIN/ACK)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP protocol will reorder the packets before sending them further up the stack. This means it will wait for out of order packets according to the sequence number, ask for retransmission if needed, etc. and wait for the last ack before closing the connection.

You can find the TCP state diagram here:
http://www.ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/tcpTutorialNotes.html#ST

Comment: so, if PKT2 and PKT3 are lost, since A has already half-closed, A won't retransmit PKT2 and PKT3, then B will still wait for PKT2 and PKT3, and ignore the RST(or FIN/ACK)?

Comment: Even if A sends a FIN, it will still send a re-transmit to B if asked to do so. A will only close when the FIN gets ACK'ed from B. When both A and B decide to close the connection, and each receive the ACK for the FIN packets, the socket is closed.

Comment: Just to clarify one thing: should A send a RST, then the connection will be reset immediately and loss of data occurs. This is a possible attack vector to disturb a network. However under normal conditions, RST will not be sent. It can occur when host B reboots for instance and A keeps sending packets. B can then send a RST packet since it doesn't have any context for the incoming data. If it does occur under normal conditions, it will only be sent when the FIN it sent before that got ACK'ed.

Comment: Sorry, a last question: so if B has received some packets and they are in the receiving buffer(not delivered to the application layer yet). At this time, a RESET packet is received, will B discard the data in the receiving buffer or not?

Comment: Yes, in that case it will. The RST will indicate that something went wrong on the other end and whatever data was in that buffer now is irrelevant. This is why this is an effective attack in a network if you can make false RST packets to interrupt normal network operations.

Answer (score 0):

TCP guarantees sequence. That includes the sequence of the EOS. It must be delivered after all the data.

Comment: I don't follow you. what is EOS? what must be delivered? the problem is if RST or FIN/ACK arrives before the data

Comment: "the problem is if RST or FIN/ACK arrives before the data"

Doesn't matter, B will not send an ACK for A's FIN until B has all the data the sequence numbers tell it should have.

Comment: EOS is end of stream. It is caused by an incoming `FIN`, and it shows up as `recv()` returning zero. It doesn't happen until `recv()` has read all the data first. However an incoming `RST` causes *loss* of any pending data, and shows up as `recv()` returning -1 with `errno == ECONNRESET`.